# Autofix a single line in ALE

Tags: formatting, plugin-ale

When prettier tells me to take one line with a whole object and put every property on a new line, I want a key to autofix that. I know prettier has things that can be auto-fixed, but I have no idea how to trigger it with ALE (or prettier).

(note: I'm programming in JS. An object would be something like `{ prop1: 1, prop2: 2 }`)

Comment: Maybe try `:h ale-fix`? (I've never use ale but a glance at the front page of the github site says you can trigger per-buffer fixing. Individual lines may need to be specified in config, though.)

Comment: RTFM eh? Well.... it worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, you're advice was good, but actually the command I found does the whole file not one line.

Comment: I'll probably have to do some vim scripting to accomplish this. I'm busy right now, so I'll have to come back to it. (FYI `:ALEFix prettier` fixed the whole file, which is a step in the right direction)

Comment: I guess it is a bit RTFM-ish. ;) Glad it helped anyways. The part that suggested to me that ale-fix could be controlled with line granularity is this from the fourth paragraph of that help section: _Each function for fixing errors must accept either one argument `(buffer)` or
two arguments `(buffer, lines)`, representing the buffer being fixed and the
lines to fix._ .. but I may be misreading things. If you have a followup question (esp. involving vimscript) feel free to ask here.

Comment: Please post your solutions as answers to avoid ambiguity about what solved the problem(s)